# Formatting numbers in Proc Tabulate for ODS Excel

Tags: excel, format, ods

I have a simple PROC TABULATE that is working fine and produces output in Excel by ODS. However, all my numbers are shown in a kind of 'general' format without points or decimals between thousands. I tried formats such as COMMA12.2 COMMAX12.2 but only DOLLAR12.2 is working (but I don't want the dollar sign). I've tried putting the format on different places, with the same result.

Here is my code:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp;
proc tabulate data=Capital;
     var  Aantal_Producten Kapitaal;
     class Soort;
     table 
        soort all = 'Totaal' *[style=[backgroundcolor=light grey]],
        Kapitaal  * sum =' ' * f = comma12.2
        Aantal_Producten = 'Aantal Producten'  * sum =' '  * f = dollar12.2
        /indent = 4;
  run; quit;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```